# Custom routing asp.net mvc 3 issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want that in my action method, my Request.Url.Host should be available. However I don't want to set it in routedata because it will be visible to the user in the url. How can I accomplish this such that Request.Url.Host is available in my domain name variabele but now shown to the user in url? I tried adding it to Request.Form.Add("domain",Request.Url.Host) but it doesn't work because Request.Form is readonly collection.

eg:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string domain, int id) //id is the standard routedata that you get from url.
{
    ..//code
}
```

What is the best I can do? I don't want to do Request.Url.Host in every action method so I am trying this approach.

I tried to do this:

```
public class MyRoute : Route
    {
        #region '----- Method(s) -----'
        public MyRoute(string url, object defaults)
            : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
        { }

        public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            RouteData routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);

            string domain = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;

            routeData.DataTokens["domain"] = domain;

            return routeData;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

But my domain variable in my action method comes null.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want the `domain` to become part of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Complete rewrite:

You should add your custom data to `routeData.Values` instead of `routeData.DataTokens`.

```
public class MyRoute : Route
{
    #region '----- Method(s) -----'
    public MyRoute(string url, object defaults)
        : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    { }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        string domain = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;

        routeData.Values["domain"] = domain;

        return routeData;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And registering your `MyRoute` route (MVC uses the first matching route so it should go first):

```
routes.Add(new MyRoute("{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }));
```

Comment: @Jaggu see my rewritten answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! Works beautifully! I am fighting with this since last 2 hours but you solved my issue.

Comment: I had mapping wrong basically the routes.Add line. I didn't know you can set random route data without that key being a part of url.